# Can not find 'multisite' extension for TYPO3 version 11

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

How can i set up multisite in typo 3 version 11.5.8?

The extensions available on the internet are for versions upto 10.

I get the error shown in the diagram below, when I try to install multisite extension from typo3 GUI

[image: multisite extension warning]

Comment: This [link](https://t3terminal.com/blog/typo3-multisite/) gives you an introduction how to implement it without an extension.

Comment: @UrsBo The link is not up to date. For the first site, that comes with the installation of TYPO3, the link works. But for adding additional sites, one also need to set up the template. Without it, i was getting a typoscript template not found exception. The instructions in the following link worked for me. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/exceptions/main/en-us/Exceptions/1294587218.html

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is only an introduction. You always need to create a template for each website. I would recommend to use the [Sitepackagebuilder](https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/) – that gives you full control over the different websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you need this extension?

TYPO3 is out-of-the-box a multisite-system:
https://typo3.org/cms/features/massively-multisite-multilingual

---

### EXT:multisite

That extension may solve special requirements for **huge** multisites. What a "huge multisite" looks like in numbers is written in its [doc](https://docs.typo3.org/p/verdigado/multisite/main/en-us/Introduction/Performance/Index.html):

> We have a multisite installation with
>
> - 600 website (root pages)
> - 3.500 frontend users 400 frontend user groups
> - 60.000 pages
> - 250.000 content elements
> - 3.000 categories
> - 100.000 news
> - 5.000 news categories

So, for this (or a similar) use-case, the backend can get slower. EXT:multisite changes some behaviors of the backend to speed up operations.

For a "normal" TYPO3 instance with a couple of sites/rootpages and fewer pages/records, the basics of TYPO3-Core will met all requirements for a multisite.